# Angular - Okta : how to use redirectUrl with useHash: true

Tags: angular, okta

I'm using okta to authenticate my users in an angular 13 application. I've followed the okta [article](https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/sign-into-spa-redirect/angular/main/) to use their sdk, but I'm stuck to define the `redirectionUrl` with `HashLocationStrategy`.

After login I'm getting a 404 error:

[image]

My code looks like :

```
package.json {
    ...
    "@okta/okta-angular": "^5.2.0",
    "@okta/okta-auth-js": "^6.8.0",
    ...
}

app.module.ts {
//...
const oktaAuth = new OktaAuth({
    issuer: 'https://dev-xxxxx.okta.com/oauth2/default',
    clientId: 'xxxxxxx',
    redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/login/callback',
    responseMode: 'query',
    pkce: true
});
//...
}
```

In okta, login section. I've this configuration :
[image]

If I try to add a `#` in the `redirectionUrl` definition, I get the following message :

[image]

I've also added CORS rules :

[image]

Is there any way to use okta with `useHash: true` ?

Comment: We have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

No, hash's can't be used in OAuth redirect URLs.

https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-3.1.2

> The endpoint URI MUST NOT include a fragment component

Comment: what about this https://github.com/okta/okta-auth-js#strategies-for-obtaining-tokens ?

Answer (score 0):

Since we have the same problem, I have found a solution or a work around for this. Instead of catering the issue to use hash in the URL, you could try to instead adjust your app to remove the hash. Kindly refer to the guide below. Tested it and it works like a charm.

https://nphau.medium.com/angular-remove-hash-from-url-like-a-charm-bd4c2f1c0641

Comment: ok I let you know when I try it, thanks ;)